# click on text inside ng-repeater using javascript for protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click

[pls click here for element link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acHit.jpg)

**how to click on the ng-click using ng-repeater?**

i can see all the elements per index using below code but i cannot click on the elements.

```
element.all(by.repeater('debitCard in debitCards track by $index')).each(function(element, index) {

    element.getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log(index, text);
    });

});
```

Comment: You can edit the question and add them in properly

Comment: Please edit your question and add there relevant info there - no one will read code in comments...

Answer (score 0):

In 'a' tag,href is take precedence over ng-click.if you want ng-click to take precedence,make "href" attribute to be assign like below

"   a href ng-click=""  "

or else

change the 'a' tag to anything else like 'li'.

Comment: Thanks but this is what is available for me to test. i cannot change them.